# Where does winetricks install stuff

Tags: macos, wine

Where does winetricks install packages? I installed steam using the command 'winetricks steam' and I couldn't find it in ~/.wine/drive_c or just anywhere in ~/.wine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it

$HOME/.local/share/wineprefixes

more info on https://code.google.com/p/winetricks/wiki/WhereAppsGo